# Why does mocking a react context in jest return undefined?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-context

Example code:

**AuthButton.txx**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { AuthenticationContext, AuthenticationProvider } from '@mylocation/myresource';

export const AuthButton = () => {
  console.log('LoginButton, ', {AuthenticationContext, AuthenticationProvider}) 
  // both undefined ???

  const { loginWithRedirect } = useContext(AuthenticationContext);

  return (
    <button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}>
     AuthButton
    </button>
  );
};
```

When doing console.log of AuthenticationContext and AuthenticationProvider above, they are both undefined. But below I am mocking those before passing in.

**AuthButton.test.tsx**

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useMemo } from 'react';
import { fireEvent, render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { AuthButton } from './AuthButton';

const mockLoginWithRedirect = jest.fn();

const loginWithRedirect = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    mockLoginWithRedirect();
    resolve({});
  });
};

const AuthenticationContext = createContext({
  loginWithRedirect,
});

export const AuthenticationProvider = ({ children }) => {

  const value = useMemo(
    () => ({
      loginWithRedirect,
    }),
    [loginWithRedirect],
  );
  return <AuthenticationContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthenticationContext.Provider>;
};

jest.mock(
  '@mylocation/myresource',
  () => {
    return {
      AuthenticationContext,
      AuthenticationProvider,
    };
  },
  { virtual: true },
);

describe('AuthButton', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it('should call loginWithRedirect when AuthButtonn is clicked', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(
      <AuthenticationProvider>
        <AuthButton />
      </AuthenticationProvider>,
    );
    act(() => {
      fireEvent.click(getByText('AuthButton'));
    });
    expect(mockLoginWithRedirect).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I understand that if I mock the resource then the original import of '@mylocation/myresource' is undefined, but I am overwriting it with new return data in my jest mock. For some reason though it is not passing through.
Any ideas?